# Connect to Raspberry Pi through ssh from different network

Tags: ssh, networking, raspberry-pi

I want to access my raspberry pi through ssh from another network than my home's
I set my raspberry to use a static ip and mapped port 23456 to it (with TCP protocol)
I then tried `ssh -p 23456 my_username@my_global_ip` which yelded a timeout

In general, answers I found on the internet were 8 years old (it's why I'm writing this question) but I tried this:

- I did the same with port 22 to check that it wasn't because of my raspi not listening to port 23456, it didn't change anything
- I tried to allow this port in my raspi's firewall, I don't even have one
- I saw that my router may not allow this at all (btw how to find out if it doesn't?)

Any help?

Comment: Probabli if you have a router you are behind a NAT you need to open the port on the router.

Comment: I already did it for ports 23456 and 22, that's what I meant by "mapped port 23456 to it", I may not have the right technical words

Comment: Okay not a proper answer but take a look on https://www.noip.com/

Comment: I knew about this but didn't want to use third party services.
I may use this anyway as I still can't figure it out